# Inheitance not working while workig with pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

although we are printing `bval`, output is showing value of `dval` as well. Whats actual logic does compiler using?  My expected output was `00000 00000`, but I m getting output as `00000 01010`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {
 public:
   int bval;
   base() { bval = 0; }
};

class deri : public base {
  public:
    int dval;
    deri() { dval = 1; }
 };

 void SomeFunc(base *arr , int size) {
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++, arr++)
     cout << arr-> bval;
   cout<<endl;
 }

 int main() {
   base BaseArr[5];
   SomeFunc(BaseArr, 5);
   deri DeriArr[5];
   SomeFunc(DeriArr, 5);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. You cannot treat arrays polymorphically. Searching for duplicate...

Comment: or... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411844/polymorphism-pointers-to-arrays

Answer (score 3):

You are cheating the system, and getting "slicing".

Since `deri` is larger than `base`, when you do `arr++`, the pointer is only advanced an `base` object forward.

The solution is to have an array of pointers, and passing a `base **arr`, like this:

```
base *foo[5];
base BaseArr[5];
SomeFunc(BaseArr,5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
   foo[i] = &BaseArr[i];
}
SomeFunc(foo, 5);
```