# Using an Array on a Polymorph design

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism

I am just starting to really understand Polymorphism, but still this is a new topic for me.
So here is my Problem: I have to classes, enemy and Bankrobber. However Bankrobber inherits from 
enemy. I tried to make an array of 10 Bankrobbers. A global function should then use all members of the array to do something, well I guess this is a worthless description, so here is the code:

```
void UpdateEnemies(Enemy * p_Enemy, int counter) { 
    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < counter;i++) { 
        p_Enemy[i].Update(); 
    } 
}

int main(void) { 
    BankRobber EnemyArray[10]; 
    Enemy * p_Enemy = new BankRobber(13,1); 
    UpdateEnemies(EnemyArray,10); 
    system("PAUSE"); 
};
```

I apologize for any language mistakes. I am not a native speaker

My actual Problem: This code is just for practicing, so the purpose is just to see 10 times Update on the console, for each member of the Array. So the function UpdateEnemys should call all the enemy.update functions. The method with the type casting is not exactly what I want, cause it is not dynamicly anymore, as there will be more enemy later on. Not only Bankrobbers.

Comment: I am very sorry for this comment, but I can't get the highlighting to work.

Comment: void UpdateEnemies(Enemy * p_Enemy, int counter)
{
 for(unsigned int i = 0;i < counter;i++)
 {
  p_Enemy[i].Update();
 }
}
int main(void)
{
 BankRobber EnemyArray[10];
 Enemy * p_Enemy = new BankRobber(13,1);
 UpdateEnemies(EnemyArray,10);
 system("PAUSE");
};

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but you should read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/array-derived-vs-base.html.

Comment: it is just for practicing purpose, I understand, that there are better methods on realizing, what I want to do. It's just, the code doesn't wok, because it trys to refer something, that doesn't exist

Comment: You forgot to explain what exactly your problem is. What is that code supposed to do and what happens instead?

Comment: You can't treat arrays polymorphically.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411844/polymorphism-pointers-to-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring an array of BankRobber like this

```
BankRobber EnemyArray[10];
```

But than acessing them through the base class pointer like this

```
Enemy * p_Enemy;    
p_Enemy[i].Update();
```

Wouldn't work. That's because indexing an array `p_Enemy[i]` will be done by using the offcet `sizeof(Enemy)`
But `sizeof(BankRobber)` is probably bigger than from `sizeof(Enemy)`, so p_Enemy[i] will end up in the wrong place

You should use a vector of pointers instead, like

```
std::vector<Enemy*>
```

That way you can also use polymorphism if you add pointers to different objects into the vector. And you don't need to pass the ugly `int counter` around

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphism only works on *single* objects, accessed by a reference or pointer to a base class. It does not work on an *array* of objects: to access array elements, the element size must be known, and that's not the case if you have a pointer to a base class.

You would need an extra level of indirection: an array of pointers to single objects, along the lines of

```
void UpdateEnemies(Enemy ** p_Enemy, int counter) { 
    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < counter;i++) { 
        p_Enemy[i]->Update(); 
    } 
}

int main() {
    // An array of Enemy base-class pointers
    Enemy * EnemyArray[10]; 

    // Populate with pointers to concrete Enemy types
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
         EnemyArray[i] = new BankRobber;
    }

    // Of course, the array can contain pointers to different Enemy types
    EnemyArray[9] = new Dragon;

    // The function can act polymorphically on these
    UpdateEnemies(EnemyArray,10);

    // Don't forget to delete them. Enemy must have a virtual destructor.
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
         delete EnemyArray[i];
    }
}
```

You should also consider using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) types, such as containers and smart pointers, to manage these dynamic resources; but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you didn't say exactly what is the problem.

Did you try casting inside your code? Something like:

```
void UpdateEnemies(Enemy * p_Enemy, int counter) { 
    BankRobber *pRobber = (BankRobber*)p_Enemy;
    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < counter;i++) { 
        pRobber[i].Update(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Ben Hymers: Can you explain why it will not work? (apart from OP's comment which I understand, when he said that he may have other enemies other than BankRobber - and in that case, I understand). I couldn't deduce why it won't work from other answers..

Comment: Well, it'll work if `UpdateEnemies` knows for sure that the passed in `p_Enemy` points to an array of `BankRobber`s, but that's not safe in general :) You could similarly pass in a `void*` or `intptr_t` and cast to `BankRobber`; it's just as nasty.

Comment: @Ben Hymers: Well, I see, but at least it works. I just suggested it as a possible solution ...

Comment: It's not a solution though; the OP said he wants it to work with other subclasses of `Enemy`. Your code looks to callers like it works on pointers to the base `Enemy` but in fact breaks unless they're actually `BankRobber`s. I'm not trying to nitpick or be nasty, it's just wrong, sorry!

Comment: @Ben Hymers: The OP said he wanted it to work with other subclasses of `Enemy` _after_ I posted this solution ...

Comment: Ok, but even before the edit, the question title referred to polymorphism, which your answer doesn't show. You may have gotten rid of the access violation in the OP's snippet of code but that's just fixing a symptom of the root cause, which is that arrays can't be used polymorphically. Seriously, this is a bad answer, I don't see how you can defend it. Apologies if I'm coming across as an argumentative anonymous internet person; I'm just trying to help you understand, honestly!