# Why primitive array of polymorphic types is dangerous

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism

To help better understand my question, I'm referring to a topic discussed in the book "The C++ Programming Language 4th edition" chapter 27 section 2.1.

The author is talking about the danger of polymorphic types and built-in arrays.
He gives the following example:

```
void maul(Shape∗ p, int n) // Danger!
{
    for (int i=0; i!=n; ++i)
        p[i].draw(); //looks innocent; it is not
}

void user()
{
    Circle image[10]; // an image is composed of 10 Circles
    // ...
    maul(image,10); // ‘‘maul’’ 10 Circles
    // ...
}
```

We're told that Shape is an abstract size of size 4 and Circle inherit Shape and add an extra 2 members, center and radius which adds to the type size, hence, `sizeof(Circle)>sizeof(Shape)`.
Now the author explains that given the following view for example:

```
user() view: image[0] image[1] image[2] image[3]<br/>
maul() view: p[0] p[1] p[2] p[3]
```

The call of `p[1].draw()` (emphasis on p[**1**], for p[0] it will call the right function) will fail because there's no virtual function pointer where it's expected.

Now I know how virtual function tables works, but I don't understand how the size of the type or its layout affect a virtual function call? When the compiler see a call to a virtual function doesn't it replace it with something similar to:

```
p[1]._vfptr->draw_impl();
```

Assuming I'm right, how is the size of the derived object/its layout broke the call for it.

Comment: How do you expect to do a virtual function call when you don't even have the correct addresses of the `Circle` objects?

Comment: Do you understand that `image + 1 != p + 1`?

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I've read about slicing and it made it clear for me.

Comment: @CoryKramer: I disagree with duplicated, here `p[1]` is not even a correct `Shape`.

Comment: [polymorphism-pointers-to-arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411844/polymorphism-pointers-to-arrays) seems a better duplicate.

Comment: @Jarod42 yea this is exactly my question. Weird that it didn't came up in the suggestion list of already asked questions, or maybe I didn't saw it.

Comment: @Jarod42 I agree your link better covers this question in particular. I removed my Mjölnir vote

Comment: The focus on "primitive" arrays is somewhat of a red herring: you can't do this with `std::vector` either (it won't compile).

Comment: Yeah, duplicate, though I would rather see a fresh answer with a simple explanation.. "a pointer to the next base class subobject of the next member of the derived class array." - let's just say, it's not beginner friendly...

Answer (score 0):

When `i` is 0, this works:

```
p[i].draw(); // Shape* p
```

`p[0]` is the same as `*(p+0)` which is just `*p`, and calling a function through a base class pointer is exactly what virtual functions are designed to support.

But what about when `i` is 1?  Now you have `p[1]` which is `*(p+1)`.  And what is `p+1`, well, it's the address of the "next" object after `p`.  But array indexing is a concept from C, where there are no virtual tables or derived classes, so the indexing is done by adding the *compile-time* `sizeof(*p)` which is `sizeof(Shape)`.  You end up with something like:

```
((Shape*)((char*)p + sizeof(Shape)))->draw();
```

That is, increment `p` (the beginning of the array of `Circle`s) by `sizeof(Shape)` bytes, then dereference it to call `draw()`.  But this indexing is wrong, because it should be `sizeof(Circle)` bytes.  And C, which gives us the array type, does not give us any tools to deal directly with this, because it did not foresee C++.

Note that C++11 `std::array<>` won't help, other than making the above a compile-time error (which I suppose is much better than the runtime *undefined behavior* you get with the C-style array).  And good old `std::vector<>` is the same.  You can store an array of pointers, in which case they should usually be smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr`.  That works because pointers to any type (apart from pointers to member functions!) are the same size, so indexing through an array of them works fine.